# How to index each steps of moving disk in Tower of Hanoi (recursive approach)

Tags: c, function, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Printing moving disk from source to destination in TOH( Tower of Hanoi) can easily write in C/C++.(with recursive function)
But how can we print index each step ?
C code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void tower( int disk, int peg1, int peg2, int peg3);// function declaration
int main()
{
    int disk;
    int peg1= 1, peg2= 2, peg3= 3;//numbering 
    puts("enter disk");
    scanf("%d", &disk);//read disks
    tower(disk, peg1, peg2, peg3);//function using
    return 0;
}
void tower( int disk, int peg1, int peg2, int peg3)//function definition
{
    
    if(disk ==1)//if only 1 disk is avialable
    {
    printf("move disk from peg%d to peg%d\n",peg1,peg3);//moving disk from source to destination
    }
    else
    {
      tower(disk-1, peg1,peg3,peg2);//moving n-1 disk from peg 1 to peg2 using peg3
      printf("move disk from peg%d to peg%d\n", peg1,peg3);//move last biggest disk
      tower(disk-1,peg2,peg1,peg3);//moving n-1 disk from peg2 to peg3 using peg1
    }
```

It works and prints output.

But Is there any way to index(1,2,...)each step like-

1. move disk from peg1 to peg3
2. move disk from peg1 to peg2

Comment: [Edit] and show us already the code you've written so far. And then make clear what the meaning of _printing index each step_ is. Also read this: [ask].

Comment: Above recursive function prints output, but how to numbering( 1,2,3,4....) each printing line(step)?

Comment: Why am I receiving -ve votes???????

Comment: Because the first version of your question was vey bad. Now it's better and I retracted my downvote. But it's still somewhat unclear. You should add an example of input and desired vs. actual output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that you do not need to `printf` something in your else
branch since this is being managed by your recursive function base
case.

To print the index, the easiest solution (if we rule out global
variables) would be to give your recursive function an additional
pointer argument referencing an integer that is the number of lines printed.  Each time you
print a line, the integer referenced by this pointer is incremented by 1.  This gives function `tower_ptr` below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void tower_ptr(int * index, int disk, int src, int tmp, int dst) {    
  if(disk == 1) {
    (*index) ++;
    printf("%d. move %d -> %d\n", *index, src, dst);
  } else {
    tower_ptr(index, disk - 1, src, dst, tmp);
    tower_ptr(index, 1, src, - 1, dst);
    tower_ptr(index, disk - 1, tmp, src, dst);
  }
}

int main() {
  int index = 0;
  int disk;
  puts("enter disk");
  scanf("%d", &disk);
  tower_ptr(&index, disk, 1, 2, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

Another solution is to give your function an additional parameter
which is the next index to print.  The function returns the number of
indexes printed.  This gives function `tower_int` below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int tower_int(int index, int disk, int src, int tmp, int dst) {    
  if(disk == 1) {
    printf("%d. move %d -> %d\n", index + 1, src, dst);
    return index + 1;
  } else {
    index = tower_int(index, disk - 1, src, dst, tmp);
    index = tower_int(index, 1, src, - 1, dst);
    index = tower_int(index, disk - 1, tmp, src, dst);
    return index;
  }
}

int main() {
  int index = 0;
  int disk;
  puts("enter disk");
  scanf("%d", &disk);
  tower_int(0, disk, 1, 2, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HIMANSHUNARAYAN  Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it solved your problem...

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. once again thanks @qouify

Comment: @HIMANSHUNARAYAN You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: Hello @qouify, Please clear some doubt -----     '-1' used for temp in 2nd recursive function , Is it necessary(For 1 disk ,this step  is same as base case)?????.  Any numerical value( +ve/-ve instead of -1) prints same result. Its also true if '-1' is replaced with ' tmp'(As for 1 disk , there is no need of temp).

Comment: Hello @HIMANSHUNARAYAN. Yes exactly. I just put `-1` here to mean basically that this is not used and that we don't care. We could have put `-1`, `0`, `54564` or `tmp` the result would the same as parameter `tmp` is unused in the base case.